# General way to convert a loop into a stream

Tags: java, loops

I am learning about streams in java8 using lambdas and so on. If I have a while loop with a condition like:

```
while(x > 10){
   do something
   stop when condition is no more
   }
```

how do I convert it to the stream version?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes. Breaking when the condition of the loop is meet is what bothers me

Comment: Please post the code that you have already tried, so we can see where you are going wrong.

Comment: (int)IntStream.of(10).mapToDouble(x -> x %10) etc.. the do something part is not the problem I have. Its the iterating until the loop condition is meet.

Answer (score 2):

Stream is not a replacement of loop. You cannot just convert in a general way.

Comment: Ok thanks didn't know. Thought you could make a stream version of any arbitrary loop

Comment: Well you *possibly* could.  But a recipe for doing this in a general way would most likely be horribly complicated, and the result would be horrible, inefficient code.